# Custom Button Background with diagonal Cutting View

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I want to set background as shown in image
[image]

i have tried many tutorial for example

- https://medium.com/@adinugroho/create-diagonal-cut-view-in-android-5a376eca6a1c
- https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout

but not getting proper result,can anyone help me to get perfect result.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is probably a .png image used as background of the component.

Comment: You can easily achieve this by using a png of only orange part.

Comment: @ADM i don't want to use a image,as it will increase apk size ,i have many buttons with different size so it need more number of image for each also click effect is also there

Comment: Well I am not sure whether it's possible with xml drawable but it will surly done with canvas . Meanwhile add some more details to your question . Arrow is independent for click or not ??

Comment: yes,arrow is independent for click

Comment: I think you should have a look at 9-patch drawables, seems like this is a good use-case for that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

**Please do note that you may need to tweak the `width` and `height` of the `Button` to make it work for you.**

You can do this with `vector` and `layer-list` drawables.

> diagonal_shape

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:viewportWidth="52.652084"
    android:viewportHeight="21.166666">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F48733"
        android:pathData="M31.214,0.036 L2.229,0.027C0.332,0.026 0.104,0.811 0.101,1.862l-0.047,16.618c-0.003,1.466 -0.185,2.731 1.932,2.729L51.342,21.175c1.381,0.096 1.798,-0.748 0.581,-2.647L45.639,9.214 40.544,1.907C39.687,0.67 39.285,0.305 38.061,0.138 36.744,-0.042 34.414,0.081 31.214,0.036Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.11766827"/>
</vector>
```

> ic_arrow_forward

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z"/>
</vector>
```

> button_background_layer_list

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:gravity="end"
        android:left="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3B5998" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/diagonal_shape"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:right="20dp" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:right="5dp" />

</layer-list>
```

**Now just set `button_background_layer_list` as `Button` background in `xml` like**

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background_layer_list"
```

This looks something like this.
[image]

The new button after updating the code looks like this, hopefully this is how you want it.
[image]

Comment: thank you for reply,i have tried same solution,but issue is desired output i want a thin border of button,divider between orange and blue have a rounded corner,can you look at image in answer.i want a same result

Comment: Okay that can be done as well, as soon as I get home I'll update my answer.

Comment: can you please suggest any tool or software for generate SVG file

Comment: Hi, I apologize it took me so long. I have updated my answer, hopefully this is what you wanted. And I use Inkscape  to draw vectors and SVGs but you may use any program you like.

Comment: button look perfect as i want,because of ` android:width="150dp"` of diagonal_shape blue part get increased in high dp devices or small device it look good

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Nexus 4 (768*1280)

Comment: are you using `match_parent` as Button's width?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167233/discussion-between-jzm-and-ashish-walia).

Comment: i am using 15 as min SDK version