# How to customize the tablayout of viewpager with diagonal dividers?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Here the white one is selected tab. The image is attached here>>>>>>>>>

[image]

Comment: What is the selected tab in this case?

Comment: the white one is selected.

Comment: Hello loop stack,can you share your tablayout code,i want to know.please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest I can think. You can get two png background images for Tablayout background for both cases.

You will have two png in your case. Say `bg_tab_first.png` and `bg_tab_second.png`. Now change background accordingly.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int selected = tab.getPosition();
        tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, selected == 0 ? R.drawable.bg_tab_first : R.drawable.bg_tab_second));
    }
});
```

I would suggest make drawable instead of using PNG cause flexibility. [Follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376886/6891563) to get diagonal view.

Comment: Very clever. I love that answer. Thank you. I will try to  implement that :).